Ubuntu Studio 24.04 installer does not remove video, graphics and photography packages
I have just installed Ubuntu Studio (Ubuntu 24.04) on a virtual machine without any difficulty.
We only want to use it for audio tasks in an embedded system so it has to be the lightest version, only a VST Host will run it headless. Everything that is plus and not audio related and I note, great in this Ubuntu flavor, is unnecessary in this installation (video, photo, etc.).
I thought I could remove them with the installer, but it starts the process, asks for root access, but everything stays in the original state, even after rebooting.
It wouldn't be bad if you could choose which multimedia stuff you want to use at the first installation, but now I'm more interested in why the uninstall doesn't work.
https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/
These could also be used, but the "Ubuntu Studio installer" would be best to withdraw unnecessary packages:
sudo apt purge ubuntustudio-video ubuntustudio-video-core
sudo apt autoremove

syslog:
2024-07-02T13:15:00.590430+01:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: Dialog accepted
2024-07-02T13:15:00.597528+01:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: COMPLETED
2024-07-02T13:15:00.597578+01:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: Completed:  true
2024-07-02T13:15:00.597591+01:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: Finishing obtaining privileges
2024-07-02T13:15:00.597621+01:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: Listener adapter polkit_qt_listener_initiate_authentication_finish
2024-07-02T13:15:00.597650+01:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: polkit_qt_listener_initiate_authentication_finish callback for  0x5f18c70a3600
2024-07-02T13:15:00.598199+01:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: Finish obtain authorization: true
2024-07-02T13:15:00.606511+01:00 ustudio-VM kwin_x11[2590]: kwin_core: XCB error: 152 (BadDamage), sequence: 35229, resource id: 16797904, major code: 144 (DAMAGE), minor code: 3 (Subtract)
2024-07-02T13:15:00.615947+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5900]: qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
2024-07-02T13:15:00.616067+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5900]: qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
2024-07-02T13:15:00.616099+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5900]: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
2024-07-02T13:15:00.616112+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5900]: Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
2024-07-02T13:15:00.716778+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5877]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 26:  5900 Aborted                 (core dumped) qapt-batch --update
2024-07-02T13:15:00.739300+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[5903]: Failed to open display
2024-07-02T13:15:01.230990+01:00 ustudio-VM CRON[5924]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
2024-07-02T13:15:01.719029+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 32: echo: write error: Broken pipe
2024-07-02T13:15:02.720496+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 33: echo: write error: Broken pipe
2024-07-02T13:15:03.721749+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 34: echo: write error: Broken pipe
2024-07-02T13:15:04.636693+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5985]: Warning: --window-icon is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of zenity; Treating as --icon.
2024-07-02T13:15:04.644232+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[5985]: Failed to open display
2024-07-02T13:15:04.722908+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 35: echo: write error: Broken pipe
2024-07-02T13:15:05.724180+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 36: echo: write error: Broken pipe
2024-07-02T13:15:06.725238+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 37: echo: write error: Broken pipe
2024-07-02T13:15:07.726537+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 38: echo: write error: Broken pipe
2024-07-02T13:15:07.832921+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[5994]: Unknown key gtk-modules in /home/ustudio/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
2024-07-02T13:15:07.848539+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[5994]: Theme directory places/128 of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
2024-07-02T13:15:07.848628+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[5994]: Theme directory places/scalable of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
2024-07-02T13:15:08.022026+01:00 ustudio-VM xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2707]: xdp-kde-settings: Group  "org.freedesktop.appearance"  doesn't exist
2024-07-02T13:15:08.023105+01:00 ustudio-VM xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2707]: xdp-kde-settings: Namespace  "org.gnome.desktop.a11y.interface"  is not supported
2024-07-02T13:15:08.024224+01:00 ustudio-VM xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2707]: xdp-kde-settings: Namespace  "org.gnome.desktop.interface"  is not supported
2024-07-02T13:15:08.024977+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[5994]: Using GtkSettings:gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme with libadwaita is unsupported. Please use AdwStyleManager:color-scheme instead.
2024-07-02T13:15:08.074719+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[5994]: Theme directory places/128 of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
2024-07-02T13:15:08.074800+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[5994]: Theme directory places/scalable of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
2024-07-02T13:15:08.482193+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[6079]: Warning: --window-icon is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of zenity; Treating as --icon.
2024-07-02T13:15:08.727704+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 39: echo: write error: Broken pipe
2024-07-02T13:15:09.729196+01:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 40: echo: write error: Broken pipe
2024-07-02T13:15:11.767049+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[6079]: Unknown key gtk-modules in /home/ustudio/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
2024-07-02T13:15:11.783668+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[6079]: Theme directory places/128 of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
2024-07-02T13:15:11.783771+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[6079]: Theme directory places/scalable of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
2024-07-02T13:15:11.972268+01:00 ustudio-VM xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2707]: xdp-kde-settings: Group  "org.freedesktop.appearance"  doesn't exist
2024-07-02T13:15:11.973598+01:00 ustudio-VM xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2707]: xdp-kde-settings: Namespace  "org.gnome.desktop.a11y.interface"  is not supported
2024-07-02T13:15:11.974781+01:00 ustudio-VM xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2707]: xdp-kde-settings: Namespace  "org.gnome.desktop.interface"  is not supported
2024-07-02T13:15:11.975589+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[6079]: Using GtkSettings:gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme with libadwaita is unsupported. Please use AdwStyleManager:color-scheme instead.
2024-07-02T13:15:12.026234+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[6079]: Theme directory places/128 of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
2024-07-02T13:15:12.026339+01:00 ustudio-VM zenity[6079]: Theme directory places/scalable of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
2024-07-02T13:15:20.985711+01:00 ustudio-VM kwin_x11[2590]: kwin_core: XCB error: 152 (BadDamage), sequence: 42044, resource id: 16800394, major code: 144 (DAMAGE), minor code: 3 (Subtract)
2024-07-02T13:15:20.987634+01:00 ustudio-VM systemd[2155]: app-ubuntustudio\x2dinstaller-ba1e25678c5141aa8511481015f8e24e.scope: Consumed 33.832s CPU time.
2024-07-02T13:15:23.329172+01:00 ustudio-VM systemd[2155]: Started app-org.kde.kate-a2be730179bf461a8ac45700423b4358.scope - Kate - Advanced Text Editor.

journalctl:
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: Dialog accepted
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: COMPLETED
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: Completed:  true
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: Finishing obtaining privileges
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: Listener adapter polkit_qt_listener_initiate_authentication_finish
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: polkit_qt_listener_initiate_authentication_finish callback for  0x5f18c70a3600
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM polkitd[1426]: Operator of unix-session:3 successfully authenticated as unix-user:ustudio to gain ONE-SHOT authorization for action org.freedesktop.policykit.exec for unix-process:5146:87052 [/bin/bash /usr/bi>
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1[2683]: Finish obtain authorization: true
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM pkexec[5877]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by ustudio(uid=1000)
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM pkexec[5877]: ustudio: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/ustudio] [COMMAND=/usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer ubuntustudio-graphics ubuntustudio-photography ubuntustudio-video]
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM kwin_x11[2590]: kwin_core: XCB error: 152 (BadDamage), sequence: 35229, resource id: 16797904, major code: 144 (DAMAGE), minor code: 3 (Subtract)
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5900]: qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5900]: qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5900]: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5900]: Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5877]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 26:  5900 Aborted                 (core dumped) qapt-batch --update
Jul 02 13:15:00 ustudio-VM zenity[5903]: Failed to open display
Jul 02 13:15:01 ustudio-VM CRON[5923]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
Jul 02 13:15:01 ustudio-VM CRON[5924]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 02 13:15:01 ustudio-VM CRON[5923]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 02 13:15:01 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 32: echo: write error: Broken pipe
Jul 02 13:15:02 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 33: echo: write error: Broken pipe
Jul 02 13:15:03 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 34: echo: write error: Broken pipe
Jul 02 13:15:04 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5985]: Warning: --window-icon is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of zenity; Treating as --icon.
Jul 02 13:15:04 ustudio-VM zenity[5985]: Failed to open display
Jul 02 13:15:04 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 35: echo: write error: Broken pipe
Jul 02 13:15:05 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 36: echo: write error: Broken pipe
Jul 02 13:15:06 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 37: echo: write error: Broken pipe
Jul 02 13:15:07 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 38: echo: write error: Broken pipe
Jul 02 13:15:07 ustudio-VM zenity[5994]: Unknown key gtk-modules in /home/ustudio/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
Jul 02 13:15:07 ustudio-VM zenity[5994]: Theme directory places/128 of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
Jul 02 13:15:07 ustudio-VM zenity[5994]: Theme directory places/scalable of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
Jul 02 13:15:08 ustudio-VM xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2707]: xdp-kde-settings: Group  "org.freedesktop.appearance"  doesn't exist
Jul 02 13:15:08 ustudio-VM xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2707]: xdp-kde-settings: Namespace  "org.gnome.desktop.a11y.interface"  is not supported
Jul 02 13:15:08 ustudio-VM xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2707]: xdp-kde-settings: Namespace  "org.gnome.desktop.interface"  is not supported
Jul 02 13:15:08 ustudio-VM zenity[5994]: Using GtkSettings:gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme with libadwaita is unsupported. Please use AdwStyleManager:color-scheme instead.
Jul 02 13:15:08 ustudio-VM zenity[5994]: Theme directory places/128 of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
Jul 02 13:15:08 ustudio-VM zenity[5994]: Theme directory places/scalable of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
Jul 02 13:15:08 ustudio-VM plasmashell[6079]: Warning: --window-icon is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of zenity; Treating as --icon.
Jul 02 13:15:08 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 39: echo: write error: Broken pipe
Jul 02 13:15:09 ustudio-VM plasmashell[5902]: /usr/bin/ubuntustudio-installer: line 40: echo: write error: Broken pipe
Jul 02 13:15:11 ustudio-VM zenity[6079]: Unknown key gtk-modules in /home/ustudio/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
Jul 02 13:15:11 ustudio-VM zenity[6079]: Theme directory places/128 of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
Jul 02 13:15:11 ustudio-VM zenity[6079]: Theme directory places/scalable of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
Jul 02 13:15:11 ustudio-VM xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2707]: xdp-kde-settings: Group  "org.freedesktop.appearance"  doesn't exist
Jul 02 13:15:11 ustudio-VM xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2707]: xdp-kde-settings: Namespace  "org.gnome.desktop.a11y.interface"  is not supported
Jul 02 13:15:11 ustudio-VM xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2707]: xdp-kde-settings: Namespace  "org.gnome.desktop.interface"  is not supported
Jul 02 13:15:11 ustudio-VM zenity[6079]: Using GtkSettings:gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme with libadwaita is unsupported. Please use AdwStyleManager:color-scheme instead.
Jul 02 13:15:12 ustudio-VM zenity[6079]: Theme directory places/128 of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
Jul 02 13:15:12 ustudio-VM zenity[6079]: Theme directory places/scalable of theme ubuntustudio-dark has no size field
Jul 02 13:15:20 ustudio-VM kwin_x11[2590]: kwin_core: XCB error: 152 (BadDamage), sequence: 42044, resource id: 16800394, major code: 144 (DAMAGE), minor code: 3 (Subtract)
Jul 02 13:15:20 ustudio-VM systemd[2155]: app-ubuntustudio\x2dinstaller-ba1e25678c5141aa8511481015f8e24e.scope: Consumed 33.832s CPU time.
Jul 02 13:15:23 ustudio-VM systemd[2155]: Started app-org.kde.kate-a2be730179bf461a8ac45700423b4358.scope - Kate - Advanced Text Editor.
Jul 02 13:15:25 ustudio-VM plasmashell[6097]: Hspell: can't open /usr/share/hspell/hebrew.wgz.sizes.


If you uncheck a package, bu that package is not removed, then first check your logs. If the issue is reproducible on a stock install with zero modifications, then please file a bug report.

It is reproducible and you can see what is happening in the logs.
Can you give me some guidance on where I can make a bug report? I couldn't find any reference to this in the U - Studio flavour... THX   BTW: logs in Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/jr2sEutm

I have the exact issue on Ubuntu 24.04.1.
Nothing is actually uninstalled/removed when unchecking the box next to the metapackage bundle.
My partial workaround:
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntustudio-audio ubuntustudio-audio-core ubuntustudio-audio-plugins ubuntustudio-installer
sudo apt-get autoremove

